# What use as Database for developing asp.net vNext + Entity Framework 7 on OSX

Tags: macos, mono, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to set up my environment for developing asp.net vNext + Entity Framework 7 on my OSX.

Apparently, there is no provider for MySQL neither PostgreSQL yet. Thus, what can be used as database for developing on OSX?

What you folks have been doing for develop asp.net vNext on OSX? Or should I set up a Windows VM?

Any suggestion?

I've got even an open issue on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1340) on this topic.

Cheers

Comment: You can use SQL Azure

Comment: You could also try SQLite, check this post out (not mine): http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-use-sqlite-in-asp-net-5/.

Comment: Hi folks,

Well, I've decided to follow @VictorHurdugaci suggestion and use the Azure as datasource.

Then, I don't need to have any database locally, and I can develop tranquilly on my OSX.

My customer, however, requested me to use EF6 instead of EF7, once the EF7 is still in their initial stage of development at the moment.

What would you say about this? Do you guys agree? If so, can I develop vNext normally using EF6 on my OSX?

Cheers.

Comment: EF6 is not designed to be cross-platform, so I expect you'll have problems (or find it impossible) to run on non-Windows.

Comment: I would love to know how to get Azure to work from mono on OSX.  Mono's implementation of SqlConnection.cs doesn't seem to support encrypted connections, which is a requirement for Azure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We will have a PostgreSQL and/or MySQL provider for EF7 (either delivered by our team or we'll work with a provider writer to help them build it). Work hasn't started on them yet though.

We haven't been focusing on EF7 on Mono at this stage, so there are likely some rough edges. We do have some folks who have successfully used it to connect to a remote SQL Server though.

Comment: Is there any example of connecting successfully to a remote SQL Server via EF7 on Mono? I couldn't find any on google. Or maybe one github/twitter contact or something? Cheers.

Comment: I don't thing using Azure with Mono is a possibility yet. Azure needs SSL all the time and Mono implementation of EF7 has no support for encryption yet. Now I'm considering to use InMemory model instead for the moment.

Comment: what do I use it with on OSX? sqlite doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

To date, no RDBMS is supported on OSX for `EF7`.

Since `(LocalDB)\v11.0` doesn't allow remote access and run on OSX/LNX, I've setup a `SQLServer2012 Express` and `SQLServer 2012 Standard Edition` hosted on a local Windows VM to establish a remote DB connection from my Visual Studio Code project.

From `Visual Studio Code` running on OSX, `EF7` fails to successfully connect and interact with those local SQL Servers.  In this instance, I was using the `ASP.NET 5` Music Store example project: [GitHub Source](https://github.com/aspnet/musicstore)

Oh, and with all the SSL requirements, `AZURE SQL Server` is out of the question as an option.

Microsoft is heading in the right direction, we'll get there, but you're dealing with bleeding edge `EF7` at the moment which is a complete reengineering from `EF6`.